# Regex search for word roots with common prefixes

Tags: sed, grep, search, gnu

I recently had a curiosity about words in the dictionary that share both "pro-" and "con-" as a prefix. So, for example, procession/concession, produce/conduce, profess/confess, progress/congress, and so on. I'm basically looking for any words that match both `^pro(.+)$` and `^con(.+)$`, where the content of the capture group is the same.

My initial caveman command was:

```
sed -nr 's/^con(.+)$/\1/Ip' /usr/share/dict/words | \
xargs -I SUFFIX -n1 grep -i '^proSUFFIX$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

It seems to work, outputting a full "con-" word as long as there exists a matching "pro-" word. Problem is, it's slooow. It invokes `grep` for every potential match, asking it to scan the whole dictionary each time. I could speed it up by making a temporary file that only has pro/con words in it, but it feels like there must be some efficient way to do this without writing a file.

Is there a tool in the GNU world that's well suited to this kind of intersection search?

Comment: Something like `egrep '^(pro|con).*' /usr/share/dict/words` might do the trick as a starting point, perhaps.  You could then put the resultant list through a `sed`, `awk`, or `grep` meatgrinder that only keeps paired words.

Comment: Aha!  `egrep '^(pro|con).* /usr/share/dict/words | sed 's/^...//' | sort | uniq -d` will give you a list of all the word-bases that have both a `pro` and `con` prefix!

Comment: `uniq -d`! very nice.

Answer (score 3):

From my earlier comment to the question itself:

```
egrep '^(pro|con).* /usr/share/dict/words | sed -nE 's/^(pro|con)(.*)/\2/p' | sort | uniq -d
```

will give you a list of all the word-bases that have both a pro and con prefix:

The initial `egrep` grabs all the words with `pro` and `con` prefixes.  We then use `sed` to strip off `pro` and `con` from the beginning of each word, `sort` the list, and then use `uniq -d` to show *ony* entries on the list that have duplicates.

Comment: The combination of `grep` and `sed` is rather unnecessary, as `sed` can do both steps in one:  `sed -nr 's/^(pro|con)(.*)/\2/p' | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: I'll update to reflect this - thanks for the tip!  Keep in mind that it only works in GNU `sed`, and not BSD `sed`.

Comment: replace `-r` with `-E` and it will work with both `seds` ... also, Peter meant you can drop `egrep`  and use just `sed`

Answer (score 0):

This will print out the words without the pro|con prefix:

```
grep '^\(pro\|con\)' /usr/share/dict/words | cut -c 4- | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 2 {print $2}'
```

Comment: I do like this, as it seems more extensible (for example, if it needed to be modified to match three or more prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case - sorted input, so all `con...` words are listed before `pro...` words - you could use `awk` to store the lines matching `^con` in an array and when you reach the lines matching `^pro`, replace `pro` with `con` and if the result is in array print the root word:

```
awk '/^con/{arr[$0]=$0}; /^pro/{c=gensub(/pro/, "con", 1)
if (c in arr) print substr(c, 4)}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

```
.....
.....
vince
vinces
vocation
vocation's
vocations
voke
voked
vokes
voking
```